# Nemo crashing the whole system at Linux Mint 19.2

Tags: linux-mint, nemo

Recently, Nemo has stopped opening my folders in Linux Mint. When I click on a folder icon, it simply does not open. After a few minutes, it even opens, but stops running and becomes impossible to use. In some cases, it freezes the entire PC. This was not happening before, and I have no idea what it can be. I tried to reinstall Nemo and Cinnamon, but it just got worse. Any idea what it might be?

Comment: Try with another browser (nautilus, thunar) to test if it's the browser or something else.

Comment: If you have a mechanical hard drive (as opposed to a solid-state drive), I'd recommend checking the condition of the drive to make sure it isn't failing.